# Being a citizen of a country but not having the passport of that country

Tags: passports, dual-nationality

What are the possible consequences of entering a country as a citizen (with dual citizenship) but without having the passport of that country? I have seen some questions that ask which passport to use in cases where people have multiple passports, but in my case there is only one passport.

Some more info: I want to travel from Ireland to Germany with my daughter, who holds the Irish citizenship through birth in Ireland and the German citizenship through me as a German parent. She only has the Irish passport. The German embassy advises to have two passports but I don't find any information about the consequences of having only one passport.

Comment: No problem. I'm dual German/US and had never any trouble entering or leaving Germany on my US passport. In contrast to the US, Germany doesn't require citizens to US a Germany passport. You just need a passport that gets you in, which the Irish one does.

Comment: Thank you for your personal experience on that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends, of course, on the country in question, since the consequences will be specified by that country's laws.  In this case, my suspicion is that it doesn't matter unless and until your daughter wants to do something in Germany that a German citizen can do but an Irish citizen cannot.  Even then, any other proof of German nationality would normally be sufficient, including a German national ID card.

Under the European Union's free movement regime, an Irish citizen can only be excluded from German territory for a very limited number of very serious reasons, so it is very unlikely that your daughter would ever find herself in a position where she needed to prove her German nationality to avoid removal to Ireland.  If she did, however, she would again need some proof of German nationality, though it would not need to be a passport.

Certain government employment may be limited to German citizens, as may be certain political offices.

A quick reading of the *[Personalausweisgesetz](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/pauswg/BJNR134610009.html)* suggests that Germans who reside abroad are exempt from its requirements.  If that is correct, then there would be no consequences for failing to have a German identification document, unless even a short visit is considered a period of residence for the purpose of the law.  If your daughter is over 16 then you may want to look into that further.

Comment: Cheers @phoog. Age (and the options that come with it) is of no concern at the moment, she can't even hold a spoon yet. :-)